# Sending sms using bulksms provider

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, urllib, bulksms

I am using bulk sms service, https://www.bulksms.com,

I am not able to send arabic message due to encoding.

```
message = بريستيج
vals = {
      'username': gateway.login,
      'password': gateway.password,
      'message': message,
      'msisdn': mobile,
}
urllib.urlencode(vals)
req = urllib2.Request(url, params)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)

I fixed this issue with: `message.encode('utf8')`

but when message send it replace char with `??? ??????`
 char

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're using BulkSMS.com's [older EAPI](http://developer.bulksms.com/eapi/submission/send_sms/), for a Unicode SMS you would have to add `dca=16bit` to the URL, and encode your message body in hex - see *How do I send Unicode (16-bit) SMSs?* [in the FAQ](http://developer.bulksms.com/eapi/submission/faq/).

It would be far easier to use [the newer JSON API](http://developer.bulksms.com/json/v1/), which will do roughly what you expected in the first place, with no extra effort:

```py
# coding=utf-8
import json
import urllib
import urllib2
import base64

data = {
      'to': '+1234567890',
      'body': 'بريستيج'
}

encodedData = json.dumps(data, encoding="utf-8", ensure_ascii=False)
request = urllib2.Request('https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages?auto-unicode=true')
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % ('your_username', 'your_password'))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
f = urllib2.urlopen(request, encodedData)
response = f.read()
f.close()
print response
```

Comment: How to convert in hex? If possible please give me an example.

Comment: I added checked with 16bit dca in message. How you convert message in hex. Its possible please give me example of json api

Comment: I've added a Python example, using the JSON API. I haven't answered your hex encoding question, because you will hopefully choose the JSON API option.